# Getting the Arraylist values from servlet to JSP page

Tags: arraylist, jstl, sybase, servlet-3.0

Please I need help on passing arraylist from servlet to the jsp page.I'm trying to populate dropdown values from Database.I have successfully connected to the Database and the values are stored in the list. The list is passed to the servlet.In the servlet, i checked by printing the values retrieved in the console. It's working fine too. Also, i set the attribute to the list and forwarded to my jsp page using request dispatcher. In my jsp page, I'm trying to get the values retrieved using jstl. I have also added the jstl jar and added the jstl tag on the top of the jsp page. I have searched many times for jstl syntax and also implemented that in my jsp. But still values are not retrieved in my dropdown.
Thanks in advance.Please someone help me.

```
            ------Success.jsp
            <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
                pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
            <%-- <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %> --%>
            <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
            <%--  <%@ page import = "pack.DtoForm" %>
            <jsp:useBean id="dform" scope="page" class="pack.DtoForm" />
            <jsp:useBean id="Countries" class="pack.ViewValuesInDB" scope="page"/>
            <%@ page import="java.util.*" %> --%>


            <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
            <html>
            <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
            <title>Success page</title>
            </head>
            <body>
            <h1>Success page</h1>
            <div class="dbstyle">
            <h4>Let's start learning connecting to the database!</h4>
            <br>
            <!-- <form action="DAOServlet" method="get" name="Countries"> -->

              <label >Countries*:</label>
            <select id="Countries" name="Countries" >
            <c:forEach items="${list}" var="listt">
            <option value="${listt.Countries}">${listt}</option>
            </c:forEach>
            </select>

            </div>


            <!--  </form> -->
            </div>

            <div>
            </div>
            </body>
            </html></pre> 

            DtoForm----------------------

            package pack;



            public class DtoForm {

                  private String Countries;

                  public String getCountries() {
                        return Countries;
                  }

                  public void setCountries(String countries) {
                        this.Countries= countries;
                  }
            }

            ViewValuesInDB----------------------------

            package pack;
            import java.sql.*;
            import java.util.ArrayList;
            import com.sybase.jdbcx.*;

            public class ViewValuesInDB {

                  Connection con = null;
                  Statement stmt = null;
                  SybDriver sybDriver = null;
                  DtoForm dform=new DtoForm();

                   //List<DtoForm>dform =new ArrayList<DtoForm>();
                  ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();

                   public ArrayList<String> makeConnection() throws Exception {
                  try
                  { 
                     sybDriver = (SybDriver) Class.forName(
                       "com.sybase.jdbc2.jdbc.SybDriver").newInstance();
                     System.out.println("Driver loaded");
                     con = DriverManager.getConnection(
                                    "jdbc:sybase:Tds:ip:port","username", "password");
                     System.out.println("Database connected");
                     Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                     String query = "select Countries from Country";
                     ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
                     while (rs.next()) {
                           String a=rs.getString(1);
                           dform.setCountries(a.toString());
                           list.add(dform.getCountries());
                     }

                    for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
                    {
                          System.out.println(list.get(i));
                    }
                     rs.close();
                     stmt.close();
                     con.close();

                    }

                  catch(Exception e)
                  {
                  System.out.println("Error is "+e.getMessage());
                  }
                  return list;
                  }

                  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
                        System.out.println("inside DB main function");
                        ViewValuesInDB sc = new ViewValuesInDB();
                    sc.makeConnection();
                  }

            }


---------------genrated html---------

            <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
            <html>
            <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
            <title>Success page</title>

            <style>
            .dbstyle
            {
            width:100%;
            height:540px;
            background-color:#FDF5E6;
            }
            </style>
            </head>
            <body>
            <h1>Success page</h1>
            <div class="dbstyle">
            <h4>Let's start learning connecting to the database!</h4>
            <br>
            <!-- <form action="DAOServlet" method="get" name="Countries"> -->

              <label >Countries*:</label>
            <div>








            <select id="Countries" name="Countries" >

            </select>

            </div>


            <!--  </form> -->
            </div>

            <div>
            </div>
            </body>
            </html>
       -------servlet modified--------
        package pack;

        import java.util.ArrayList;

        import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
        import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
        import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;


        public class DropdownServlet extends HttpServlet {
            /**
             * 
             */
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


            protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
                    HttpServletResponse response) {
        System.out.println("action is called inside dropdown");
                ViewValuesInDB daoobj = new ViewValuesInDB();
                ArrayList<String> list;
                try {
                    list = daoobj.makeConnection();
                    System.out.println(list);
                    if(null == list) 
                     {System.out.println("list is null");
                     }
                 else{
                     System.out.println("list has values");
                 }

                    request.setAttribute("list", list);
                     request.getRequestDispatcher("Success.jsp").forward(request,response);  


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

        }


            public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
                 System.out.println("inside servlet function");
                 DropdownServlet sc = new DropdownServlet();
              sc.doGet(null, null);
             }
        }
```

Comment: `list` is a List<String>. So `listt` (terrible name, BTW) is a String. So `${listt.Countries}` makes no sense, since Strings don't have a Countries property. That should generate an error. Do you have one? If so, why don't you post it? If not, what is the generated HTML?

Comment: @JB Nizet Sorry for that listt as i was trying with different names.. No i didn't get any error. The html page is generated with only an empty dropdown.

Comment: Post the generated HTML

Comment: @JB Nizet Sorry for the late reply. i have added the screenshot of my output page.

Comment: That's not what I asked. Post the generated HTML, as text. Right-click - View page source. That's the generated HTML.

Comment: i have added it.

Comment: There is no error at all, and the JSTL tags are evaluated. That just means your list is empty or null. Are you sure you're going through the servlet to execute the page? What is the URL in the browser location bar?

Comment: When i run the project, its showing the url as http://localhost:8080/Checkdropdown/ .Checkdropdown is my project name. So  is there any wrong in my servlet code? ArrayList<String> list=  daoobj.makeConnection();
  System.out.println(list);//this list getting printed.

Comment: tried this code in my servlet page-it's displaying the list values  if(null == list)  {System.out.println("list is null"); } else{ System.out.println("list has values"); }  but there is a null pointer exception at the request.setAttribute("list", list);. This is the issue am facing.

Comment: Your code can't possibly deploy. Your class doesn't even extend HttpServlet.

Comment: yes i did..but same error

Comment: This is my stack trace..inside servlet function
action is called inside dropdown
Driver loaded
Database connected
India
India
India
Australia
USA
China
Japan
Newzealand
Russia
UnitedKingdom
[India, India, India, Australia, USA, China, Japan, Newzealand, Russia, UnitedKingdom]
list has values
java.lang.NullPointerException
 at pack.DropdownServlet.doGet(DropdownServlet.java:32)
 at pack.DropdownServlet.main(DropdownServlet.java:47)                      i have modified the servlet code as given above

Comment: Well, obviously: instead of deploying your servlet to a container, you're executing a main method which invokes your doGet() method with null arguments. You seem to not understand what you're doing, what a servlet is, how it's supposed to be deployed and executed, etc. Take a step back, and read a tutorial on servlets and JSPs.

Comment: I accept I'm new to development and trying to learn. Even the server has been mapped automatically in web. xml . You try to understand my question. My question is why the values is saved as null while setting the attribute in servlet. The list contains values but while setting in attribute it's throws null pointer exception. I gave the main method inside servlet to check if the list contains values. It's just for checking purpose.

Comment: The issue is resolved. It's problem with my configuration files. Unwanted jars has been removed and onload the servlet is called.